# Vue.js computed functions with external objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to use Vue's `computed` property with an external object?

To show what I mean, here is a code example of how I imagine it:

```js
<!-- Vue file -->

<template>
    <div>{{data.auth}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import {_data} form "./data"

export default {
    computed: {
        data() { return _data }
    }
}
</script>

<!-- data.js file -->

let _auth = "123";

export let _data = {
   auth: _auth
}

setTimeOut(() => _auth = "456", 2000)
```

What I would expect from this code is that the HTML document changes after 2000ms from "123" to "456".

But as far as I can say this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Vue 3 or Vue 2?

Comment: Currently 2. But it would be no problem to change to 3

Comment: Your `_data` is not reactive, that's way is not reflecting it in html.

Comment: @ashwinbande what dose reactive mean, and how can i make it reactive?

Comment: reactive means vue can detect the changes in object and modify html according to it. the data of component is reactive; but `_data` is not.

Comment: Is it possible to make _data reactive?

Comment: Only way to make it reactive in vue2 is to change it through vue component function e.g. use `setTimeout` in created hook or so; in vue3 you can use  `reactive` directly; refer vue3 documentation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Vue 3 you can import [`ref`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#ref) to track changes:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const _auth = ref('123')

export const _data = {
    auth: _auth
}

setTimeout(() => {
    _auth.value = '456'
}, 2000)
```

---

Working snippet:

```js
const _auth = Vue.ref('123')
const _data = {
  auth: _auth
}

setTimeout(() => {
  _auth.value = '456'
}, 2000)

Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      data: _data
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ data.auth }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to abstract it to js without vue dependencies?

Comment: It isn't, as far as I know. Though, what would be the reason for that? It doesn't add extra dependencies, you're just importing from an existing one

Comment: We would like to create a JavaScript api which should be compatible with vue but also possibly with other frameworks. So some kind of solution without dependencies from vue would be optimal.

Comment: Oh, I see. Only way around that (that I can think of) is using a conditional to check if Vue is being used, if so, use something *similar* to my answer, else, use a vanilla JS version (or whatever different framework is in use).

Answer (score 2):

With [Observables](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable),  you can make data reactive

```
import Vue from "vue";

let _auth = "123";
export let _data = Vue.observable({
  auth: _auth
});

setTimeout(() => {
  _data.auth = "456";
}, 2000);
```